# Video cannot play in Ipad, but can play on desktop with using html5 video tag

Tags: html5-video

I'm using the html5 video tag to display the video call from database, but the video cannot display properly on ipad, just can display on desktop. Is it the video I calling by file path from my file server cannot support by my ipad?
Because i have do one exaple just place a video in the same folder with my .aspx file which are use to call the video. It can be work. 
Example call in same folder:

`<video id="myvideo" src="a.mp4" controls="true" width="703" height="400" type="video/mp4"></video>`

Example call from file server:

`<video id="myvideo" src="\\10.200.1.90\tgm_navi_fs\eNotice\General Notice\Article\UploadedVideos\11_140327133434_Nanotips.mp4" controls="true" width="703" height="400" type="video/mp4"></video>`

src="\10.200.1.90\tgm_navi_fs\eNotice\General Notice\Article\UploadedVideos\11_140327133434_Nanotips.mp4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the iPad thinks you're trying to access a local file, and iOS doesn't allow users direct access to the local file system. (You'll notice, iOS apps don't generally ask you to load or save work in a folder the same way desktop apps do.)

You probably need to set up a HTTP server (a.k.a. "web server", like Apache, etc.), either on the file server itself or on another machine that has access to the file server. Then you need to change the URL to use the http protocol.

So, for example, let's say you set up your web server on the file server machine and set the root to "\tgm_navi_fs\eNotice\General Notice\Article\". The video tag would then look like:

`<video id="myvideo" src="http://10.200.1.90/UploadedVideos/11_140327133434_Nanotips.mp4" controls="true" width="703" height="400" type="video/mp4"></video>`

Comment: ia alredy change to HTTP, like the example showed by you, but it also cannot work..
Is it the Ipad cannot support the HTTP also?

Comment: what happens when you paste the video URL directly into the mobile safari URL bar?

Comment: the video can play now, but the way is a bit weird...
i used HTTP also but the "/", i replaced by "\".
After that, the video can play properly now

Comment: Very strange, but I'm glad to hear it's working. Which web server are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it like the webserver from CISCO

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of reasons why the video isn't playing.
You should always provide (a piece of) your code with your question so it's easier to see what is going on.

A few things that might help you:

- **The HTML5 video tag is not properly set up.** Look at the code at [Video for everybody!](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody). There is also a lot more info on HTML5 video's in general.
- **The video doesn't have the right encoding for iOS (iPad).** Try [Miro Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) on you MP4 to convert it to an iOS compatible MP4.
- **The server is sending a wrong or no MiME type.** Make sure you are sending the right MIME types by putting the following in your .htacces for example.

**.htaccess video MIME Types:**

```
AddType video/mp4        f4v f4p m4v mp4
AddType video/ogg        ogv
AddType video/webm       webm
AddType video/x-flv      flv
```

The `flv` is usually used for a Flash fallback by plugins like [MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/).